# MS Access reports issue?

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I have an already existing report that runs off a particular query. This report runs perfectly. I was having an issue with one of the CLIENTs for the report, where I had to change a small piece of information. This required me to run some VBA code and insert all the info into a temp table. I'd like to run the same exact report, however, instead of using a query, to use the tempInfo table. Is there a way for me to do that? it's okay if I create another report, but the first report is somewhat complicated - so it would save a lot of time if I could just copy and paste at least the GROUP, SORT TOTAL so my data is displayed correctly. ANy suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the report that you are wanting to use and paste it in the navigation menu to  create a copy of it.

To use the "Temp Table" in your report, just go into design view of the newly copied report and change the Record Source to your "Temp Table."

You may also need to change the control source of any textboxes, labels, etc..